# ChartJS - Gradient in BarChart not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ChartData,
  ChartArea
} from "chart.js";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import faker from "faker";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: [],
  events: [],
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
      border: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    y: {
      grid: {
        color: "#2B2B2B"
      },
      ticks: {
        precision: 0,
        color: function (context) {
          var value = context.tick.value;
          return value < 0 ? "red" : "green";
        }
      },
      border: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
};

const labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];

export function App() {
  const chartRef = useRef<ChartJS>(null);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState<ChartData<"bar">>({
    labels: labels,
    datasets: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartRef.current;

    if (!chart) {
      return;
    }

    const gradient1 = chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient1.addColorStop(0, "rgba(231, 231, 231, 1)");
    gradient1.addColorStop(1, "rgba(231, 231, 231, 0)");

    const gradient2 = chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient2.addColorStop(0, "rgba(231, 231, 231, 0)");
    gradient2.addColorStop(1, "rgba(231, 231, 231, 1)");

    const gradient3 = chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient3.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 167, 5, 1)");
    gradient3.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 167, 5, 0)");

    const gradient4 = chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient4.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 167, 5, 0)");
    gradient4.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 167, 5, 1)");

    const chartData = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Dataset 1",
          data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -4, max: 4 })),
          backgroundColor: function (context) {
            const value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            console.log("valuevalue", value);
            return value > 0 ? gradient1 : gradient2;
          }
        },
        {
          label: "Dataset 2",
          data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -4, max: 4 })),
          backgroundColor: function (context) {
            const value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value > 0 ? gradient3 : gradient4;
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    setChartData(chartData);
  }, []);

  return <Bar ref={chartRef} options={options} data={chartData} />;
}
```

Working Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-field-9z8ebu?file=/App.tsx:0-3136

I am using ChartJS in ReactJS. I need to use two different gradients for both bars. If number is positive i want chartJS to create gradient from zero till that number and if negative create gradient in reverse from zero till negative number. Current output:

[image]